# assigning value to character array after creating variable type struct

Tags: c, structure, typedef

I am trying to do a student grade management project.

I am trying to define a variable type student of structure type using typedef

```
typedef struct info
{
    int rno;
    char name[40];
    char section[5];
    struct subdetail
    {
        char title[60];
        int code;
        int marks;
    } subject[6];
    
    double avg;
    double grade;
} student;

student s; // a variable s of student type
```

Now I want to assign values to title and code of 6 subjects in subject(structure).

I tried by `s.subject[0].title[] = "Mathematics"; and s.subject[0].code = 1234;`

This shows compilation error. How to fix it?

Comment: You can't assign to arrays, you must *copy* to them. For example using [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy). And to be honest, any decent book or tutorial should have contained that information, and if the resource you use or read doesn't then you should discard them and find new sources to learn C.

Comment: Thanx for the hint.

Comment: `strcpy(s.subject[0].title, "Mathematics");`

Comment: `s.subject[0].code = 1234;` is fine